# Return cell reference containing closest value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I'm trying to get a spreadsheet to tell me which cell(s) contain values closest to a value I provide. Without going into too much detail it's for a golf game I play, and I've done some data collection which is entered into five ranges (1w,2w etc.) What I want to do is to be able to enter a figure (for yardage), and also the wind conditions. With this information I can manually look at my data to find the best club and power to use in this situation, but I want my spreadsheet to do it for me.

So for example, I want the ball to land at 383y, and I have a -1 wind. Looking at the below, I know I'm going to have to hit a 2W at between 94-96%:

[image]

The exact value `383` does not appear in my range, so I want to know the cell reference which contains the closest match (C28). I can then use this to discover which club (B24) and what power (B28).

I've tried looking at VLOOKUP but that won't do it:

```
=VLOOKUP (a1,range,2)
```

The problem with that is if the value isn't listed, which most of the time it isn't, it will fail. I want to return the closest value, which VLOOKUP doesn't appear to do.

I suspect that MATCH may work, but I can't work out exactly how.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Besides including your research efforts, also add the formula that you used when you tried VLOOKUP.

Comment: I tried using a standard Vlookup, but found that unless there was an exact match then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Standard [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) could have three or four arguments. How many did you use?

Comment: e.g. =VLOOKUP (a1,range,2) - the problem with that is if the value isn't listed, which most of the time it isn't, it will fail. I want to return the closest value, which VLOOKUP doesn't appear to do.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> =VLOOKUP (a1,range,2)
> ```
>
> The problem with that is if the value isn't listed, which most of the
>   time it isn't, it will fail. I want to return the closest value, which
>   VLOOKUP doesn't appear to do

First, sort `range` in ascending order. You could do in place or use [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)

Try

```
=VLOOKUP(a1,SORT(range,1,TRUE),2)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, but that returns the value, whereas what I need to know is the cell reference.

Also, it does not return the value closest to the one I type in, rather the next value down in the range. So for example if my range is 415,414, 405, etc, and I lookup on 413, Vlookup returns the value 405. I would like it to find the cell containing 414, which is closer to my required value of 413.

Comment: @Danny: Add the above findings to your question as part of your progress to find the solution.